# How to fill in the 'holes' in an irregular spaced grid or array having missing data?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, statistics

Does anyone have a straight forward Delphi example of filling in a grid using Delaunay 
Triangles or kriging?  Either method can fill a grid by 'interpolating.'

What do I want to do?  I have a grid, similar to:

```
22  23  xx  17  19  18 05  
21  xx  xx  xx  17  18 07  
22  24  xx  xx  18  21 20  
30  22  25  xx  22  20 19  
28  xx  23  24  22  20 18  
22  23  xx  17  23  15 08  
21  29  30  22  22  17 09
```

where the xx's represent grids cells with no data and the x,y coordinates of each cell is 
known. Both kriging and Delaunay Triangles can supply the 'missing' points (which of course, are fictitious, but reasonable values).

**Kriging** is a statistical method to fill in 'missing' or unavailable data in 
a grid with 'reasonable' values.  Why would you need it?  Principly to 'contour' the 
data.  Contouring algorithms (like CONREC for Delphi http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/papers/conrec/index.html) can contour regularly spaced data.  Google around for 'kriging' and 'Delphi' and you eventually are pointed to the GEOBLOCK project on Source Forge (http://geoblock.sourceforge.net/  ).  Geoblock has numerous Delphi pas units for kriging based on GSLIB (a Fortran statistical package developed at Stanford).  However all the kriging/delauney units are dependent on units refered to in the Delphi uses clause.  Unfortunately, these 'helper' units are not posted with the rest of the source code. It appears none of the kriging units can stand alone or work without helper units that are not posted or in some cases, undefined data types.

**Delaunay triangulation** is described at 
http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/papers/triangulate/index.html.  Posted is 
a Delphi example, pretty neat, that generates 'triangles.' Unfortunately, I 
haven't a clue how to use the unit with a static grid. The example 'generates' a data field on the fly.

Has anyone got either of these units to work to fill an irregular data grid?  Any code or hints how to use the existing code for kriging a simple grid or using Delaunay to fill in the holes would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code posted by Richard Winston on the Embarcadero Developer Newwork Code Central titled

> Delaunay triangulation and contouring code

( ID: 29365 ) demonstrates routines for generating constrained Delaunay triangulations and for plotting contour lines based on data points at arbitrary locations.  [Richard's code](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/29365)  .  These algorithms do not manipulate and fill-in the holes in a grid.  They do provide a method for contouring arbitrary data and do not require a grid without missing values.

[image]

I still have not found an acceptable krieging algorithm in Pascal to actually  `fill-in the holes`in a grid.

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing this as an answer because it's too long to fit into a comment.

Assuming your grid really is irregular (you give no examples of a typical pattern of grid coordinates), then triangulation only partially helps. Once you have triangulated you would then use that triangulation to do an interpolation, and there are different choices that could be made.

But you've not said anything about how you want to interpolate, what you want to do with that interpolation.

It seems to me that you have asked for some code, but it's not clear that you know what algorithm you want.  That's really the question you should have asked.

For example since you appear to have no criteria for how you should do the interpolation, why don't you choose the nearest neighbour for your missing values. Or why don't you use the overall mean for the missing values. Both of these choices meet all the criteria you have specified since you haven't specified any!

Really I think you need to spend some more time explaining what properties you want this interpolation to have, what you are going to do with it etc. I also think you should stop thinking about code for now and think about algorithms. Since you have mentioned statistics you should consider asking at https://stats.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @David Kriging/Delauny are well known published interpolation methods-http://scrf.stanford.edu/resources.software.gslib.php. Kriging is sort of magic, algorithms are horrific.I use contours to map surfaces based on a min number of points.I ask how others may use existing Delphi in the Geoblock examples on grids & would accept new code. Kriging works-I use it outside Delphi.I hped the links provided give a flavor for what I want to do.Thecolumns/rows of the example are the coordinates,these are x,y,z values & can be expressed in many ways.Thanks 4 your suggestions.Simple interpol.does not work.

Comment: @SteveJG I know about both these algorithms. But since you've not said anything about what properties you want this "missing data interpolation" to have, how can you expect anyone to advise which one to use? And triangulation does nothing to fill in the missing data. If the rows and columns are the coordinates then you have a regular grid and you don't need Delauney, you can triangulate by inspection.

Comment: @SteveJG As far as I can tell, there is no answerable question here. Unless you can supply some details, I will vote to close.

Comment: @David You may know about the algorithms but may wish to read something about kriging. Sorry you can not answer the question "How to fill 'holes' in an irregular grid or array having missing data?" Kriging does exactly this on a regular grid with 'holes,' perhaps someone else can. If I find something, I will post it. Perhaps by adding the words ..."with Delphi" to the question will help with your issue. Have a nice day.

Comment: @SteveJG Kriging and triangulation are very different. Which do you want to use?

Comment: @SteveJG In case it motivates you to try harder to extract something from this exchange, my software, amongst many other things, uses triangulation to mesh bathymetry data producing a smooth interpolating surface. I have a certain amount of experience in this field but feel that your question needs to be improved in order for you to get a good answer.